# Add QMap items in a QListWidget and select the item as active

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm a newbee on QT and I'm trying to create a kalk.
It's possible to insert on a QListWidget a QMap object?

I'll explain:

I have this MainWindow

[image]

with at the bottom a QListWidget, what I want to do is to add in the List all the QMap object that I create in on the costructor and the object that I create when I'll add an attack.

baseWindow.h

```
#ifndef BASEWINDOW_H
#define BASEWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QListWidget>
#include <QPushButton>

class baseWindow : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit baseWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);

public slots:

    void changeKalkClicked();
    void addClicked();
    void clearClicked();
    void deleteClicked();
    void itemSelected();
private:

    QPushButton* addButton;
    QPushButton* clearButton;
    QPushButton* deleteButton;
    QLineEdit* displayBA;
    QMap<QString,BaseAttack> storedBA;
    QListWidget* list;

};
```

basewindow.cpp

```
baseWindow::baseWindow(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{ //Omitted the button/layout/LineEdit creation

   list  = new QListWidget;

   storedBA.insert(tr("Empty"),BaseAttack());
   storedBA.insert(tr("First"),BaseAttack());

   QListWidgetItem* prova = new QListWidgetItem;

   prova->setText(tr("Try"));
   list->addItem(prova);

}
```

It's possible? I need to create a connect from the QMap to the QListWidget?

Comment: Do you want each item to have a QMap? what is the meaning of `SIGNAL(itemClicked(QMap*))`?

Comment: No, it's the opposite. I did not explain well: I want that all the Qmap item appear in the QListWidget (in the example the item "Empty" and "First"). So, after the construction of the Kalk in the QListWidget appear the objetct "Empty" and the object "First".

The connect(list, SIGNAL(itemClicked(QMap*)), this, SLOT(itemSelected())); it's a try to see what happen (mistake)

Comment: I still do not understand, I do not know what is KALK, on ​​the other hand signals define the type of data they send, you can not change it, itemClicked send a pointer to the item pressed, you can not think that magically send a different data.

Comment: I'm suspecting that you have a predefined QMap, where the key must be the text of the item, and the value that is BaseAttack is the one you want to get it when you press an item. I am right?

Comment: what class does BaseAttack inherit from?

Comment: please edit your question and add it there

Comment: Yes, your suspect is right.

Baseattack is a sub-class that derives from Damage: the base Class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple, you just have to use the text of the item pressed, and we get the BaseAttack using the QMap, but to work in a simple way the BaseAttack class must have a copy constructor.

***.h**

```
private slots:
    void onItemClicked(QListWidgetItem *item);
```

***.cpp**

```
    storedBA.insert(tr("Empty"), BaseAttack());
    storedBA.insert(tr("First"), BaseAttack());

    QMapIterator<QString, BaseAttack> i(storedBA);
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        i.next();
        list->addItem(i.key());
    }
    connect(list, &QListWidget::itemClicked, this, &baseWindow::onItemClicked);
}


void baseWindow::onItemClicked(QListWidgetItem *item)
{
    BaseAttack ba = storedBA[item->text()];
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!!

Two more things,
1) can you explain me how this connect work?
2) on the Slot function (baseWindow::onItemClicked(QListWidgetItem *item), what the assignment do? You store on "ba" what is inside storeBA?

Comment: @Dogen do you mean `connect(list, &QListWidget::itemClicked, this, &baseWindow::onItemClicked);`?

Comment: Yes, `connect(list, &QListWidget::itemClicked, this, &baseWindow::onItemClicked)`

Comment: @Dogen I think you mean the new syntax, since I see that you use the SIGNAL and SLOT macros, now the correct thing is to use the new syntax. see https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax

Comment: Ok.

On the function `baseWindow::onItemClicked(QListWidgetItem *item)`
what the assignment does? Store on "ba" what is inside the value of "storeBA"?

Comment: @Dogen Does the BaseAttack class have a [copy constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor)?, if it has these, would be the object stored in `storedBA.insert(some_text, BaseAttack());`

Comment: No, I must create it.